# How can you change a parent background image from a nested component in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, encapsulation

For each route in my application I need to change the parent background image.  I'm using the style property in each nested component to achieve this, setting the ViewEncapsulation to None in each component so it will have a global effect.  This works, but the problem is as I navigate through the app, I'm getting multiple instances of this style in the head tag:

```
<style>...</style>
<style>...</style>
```

Here is the code for the child component:

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: '',
    templateUrl:'app/home.component.html',
    styles: [`
              .hero-unit {
                  background:url('/app/assets/images/hero-01.png');
                  width:100%;
                  height:540px;
                  background-size: cover;
                  background-repeat: no-repeat;
                  background-position: 50% 50%;
              }
            `],

    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HomeComponent {

}
```

One overrides the other which is ok until you try to navigate back to a previous page, where the effect stops working.  My question is, is there a way to remove a style property once I navigate away from that component and have it reinserted when I navigate back.  Alternatively, is there a better way to swap out the background image based on route.  I'm having a hard time finding the best method to achieve such a simple task in Angular 2.  Thanks.

Comment: Please show the code you're using to try and achieve this.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, your approaches, and your results. You'll find people willing to help if you articulate your question succinctly

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I made an edit to the post with the code in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use router data or a service.

**Router solution**

Put the image URL in the route data:

```
{ path:      'child1', 
  component: Child1Component,
  data:      { imageUrl: '/app/assets/images/hero-02.png' }
}
```

The parent component can then subscribe to route events, extract the URL and update the style property:

```
import {Component, Renderer, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  template: `<section>
    UserComponent content here, if any.
    <nav>
       <a [routerLink]="['./']">Activity</a>
       <a [routerLink]="['profile']">Profile</a>
       - child routes
    </nav>
    <div class="child-view">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <section>`
})
export class UserComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private renderer:Renderer, private elref:ElementRef) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe(_ => { 
          let childRouteSnapshot = this.route.firstChild.snapshot;
          let url = childRouteSnapshot.data.imageUrl;
          this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.elref.nativeElement.childNodes[0],
            'background-image', 'url(' + url + ')');
      })
  }
}
```

Here's a working <kbd>[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YoWevHFG4ncRVIkdjPp5?p=preview)</kbd>.  (Note that some of the code in the plunker is only half way converted to RC5.  The code shown above is all RC5.)

I had to use `childNodes[0]` because in my example `elref` was set to `ng-component` rather than the `<section>`.

**Service solution**

Use a shared service.  See Cookbook section [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).  Children components publish events (i.e., URL image strings) on an observable/subject that the parent component subscribes to.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Mark.  I like the router data param, but couldn't get your code to work.  I tried a simplified approach and got a return of undefined.  Here's the code I'm' using to retrieve the url:                                   export class AppComponent {
  imageUrl: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.imageUrl = route.snapshot.params['imageUrl'];
      console.log(this.imageUrl);
    }
}

Comment: @maximus, I updated the answer with a working Plunker.  Note that the data is not in `ActivatedRoute.params`, it is in `ActivatedRoute.data`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark for doing that.  When I try to implement this way I get "Property ‘imageUrl’ does not exist on type ‘{[name: string]: any;}’"...  My router path is { path: 'features', component: FeaturesComponent, data: {imageUrl: '/app/assets/images/hero-02.png'} },... so seems like it should work.  I did notice that our router implementations are different.  I used the NgModule setup here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html, though I've not seen any other examples of people using this method.  Maybe this is what's causing the issue?

Comment: @maximus, it shouldn't matter if you use the NgModule setup (and that is the RC5-way to do it).  If you `console.log(childRouteSnapshot)`, do you see your data?

Comment: Actually it started working all of sudden.  My editor still complains about imageUrl but the image is working.  Brilliant, thanks so much for the help!